# LINQ update some column after join table

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, asp.net-web-api

I new c#. I try to join table (It Success I can join it) and I want update some column after join and when I test code in swagger this code not error but not update in sql. please help me

```
 // PUT api/<TestJoinController>/5
        [HttpPut("{id}")]
        public ActionResult Put(int id, [FromBody] TestJ gestor)
        {
            var result = (from pre in context.StatusDocs
                          join cus in context.get_test on pre.Id equals cus.Id
                          where pre.Id == id
                           select new TestJ
                              {
                                  Id = pre.Id,
                                  SDocNumber = pre.SDocNumber,
                                  StatusDoc = pre.StatusDoc,
                                  Name = cus.Name,
                                  Address = cus.Address,
                                  Developer = cus.Developer,
                              }).FirstOrDefault();

            if (result != null)
            {
                result.Id = id;
                context.SaveChanges();

            }
            return Ok(result);
        }
```

Comment: Why is it tagged `reactjs`?

Comment: @KonradLinkowski my ui is react, sorry I tagged wrong. I will remove it.

Comment: You might want to debug that code not just do black box checking via swagger.

Comment: Is results null?  If you do not find an ID than you will not get results.  Is ID in database a string or a number?

Comment: @jdweng my result is not null but can't update it

Comment: Is ID a primary key?  You can't change an ID if it is a primary key.

Comment: If your result  doesn't contain any entity types, then no tracking is done.
In the your query, you return an anonymous type with some of the values from the entity.There are no tracked entities coming out of the query and your update  will not be applied

Comment: Maybe you should tell what you're trying to achieve. It's not clear why you need the join, nor what you intend to update. Re-assigning an Id value doesn't seem useful (and isn't allowed if it's a primary key).

Answer (score 0):

you dont need to match the id by your self. The EntityFramework does it for you.

in your case the [Frombody] Testj Object has the id of the object you wanna modify, in it and the Framework compares the id in your object to the id of the item on the database.

here is a way to do what you wanted to Do.

```
     // PUT: api/Logs/5
    // To protect from overposting attacks, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2123754
    [HttpPut("{id}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> PutLog(int id, MyLog log)
    {
        if (id != log.Id)
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }

        _context.Entry(log).State = EntityState.Modified;

        try
        {
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
        catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
        {
            if (!LogExists(id))
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            else
            {
                throw;
            }
        }

        return NoContent();
    }
```

hope it helps. If you are using visual Studio, The ide can create an API Endpoint using your dbcontext models. From there you can modify.